# Dehydrating herbs

Tags: drying, driedherbs

Can I dehydrate different kinds of herbs on different trays at the same time in my dehydrator? Or, can each tray be a different herb. I am drying sage, oregano, parsley, and thyme.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is no issue with that. If you have specific drying times for each herb then I guess you might need to take them out at different times but I can't see it being an issue.

At worst they may absorb a little of each others' odours but the effect should be small and not really change the flavour when used in coming.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I would be slightly worried about is bits falling through the tray onto the layer below, as leaves shrink and curl up when they dry.

If you have to rearrange the herbs on one shelf, you should probably do it not over the others. And I'd put the strongest/most distinctive at the bottom, probably the sage